# How can I verify the selected item in the list?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify that the selected item in the list is "to-date". When I try to use getAttribute, I get output null for the other items, and true for the selected item, but I don't see their names printed in the console. There are 4 items in the list, and all I see is null,null,null,true. But my main goal is to verify the selected item in the list. Thanks for the help!

The HTML page:

[image]

This is my code below:

```
WebElement defaultItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myAddNewCampaignForm']/ol/li[16]/select"));
List<WebElement> allOptions = defaultItem.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
System.out.println("total items " + allOptions.size());

for (int i=0; i<allOptions.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(allOptions.get(i).getText());
    System.out.println(allOptions.get(i).getAttribute("selected"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import this

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select
```

Use Select class to control drop down objects.

```
WebElement defaultItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myAddNewCampaignForm']/ol/li[16]/select"));
Select select = new Select(defaultItem);
List<WebElement> selectedOptions = select.getAllSelectedOptions();


for(WebElement option : selectedOptions){
   System.out.println(option.getText());
}
```